# Can't understand K-Truss Graph properties

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, operations-research

<sub>[Cross-posted on Operations Research SE.](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/6782/123)</sub>

I'm trying to understand K-Truss Graphs which are defined as such

> The k-truss is a subset of the graph with the
> same number of vertices, where each edge appears in at
> least $ − 2$ triangles in the original graph.

Given this example:

[image: Example]

The $4$-Truss should be $2-1-4$ since we want edges present in at least $2$ triangles of the original graph:

- edge $1-2$ is present in triangle $0-1-2$ and triangle $1-2-4.$
- edge $1-4$ is present in triangle $1-3-4$ and triangle $1-2-4.$

Is it correct?

Comment: Ummm... what is your question?

Comment: I'm wondering if my solution on the given example matches the definition and its properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is consistent with the definition you gave. But note that the $k$-truss of a graph $G = (V,E)$ is usually defined as the maximal subgraph $H = (V',E')$ such that every edge of $H$ is in at least $k-2$ triangles within $H$ (not in the original graph). According to this definition, the $4$-truss of your example graph is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's the reason why the algorithm I implemented from a pseudocode gave me a different output from what I expected at the end of the iterations, it was an empty matrix as you said...At this point if I'm not misunderstanding again, the 3-truss graph should be the original graph itself?

Comment: Yes! The $3$-truss is just the union of the triangles in the graph; in this case, the whole graph.